# Is the single page app in asp.net MVC 4 examples, "Big Shelf", SEO friendly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, singlepage

Here's [the architecture of the SPA, "Big Shelf" from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples/sample-bigshelf-application/big-shelf-architecture).

Is a page built like this SEO friendly? If I built my app this way, would it be indexable by Bing/Google/Yahoo, etc...?

I like a lot of the benefits of an SPA, but seems SEO would be a huge negative here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages that relies mainly on javascript to render their Html for sure ARE NOT SEO Friendly. This is the main drawback of the SPA tschnology and in general of all technologies that rely on client side templates. 
This is a conceptual problem that cannot be solved with any "trick". You can use them when SEO is not important, such as intranet sites, or for pages where SEO is not important also in public web sites.

Comment: Thanks... with the upcoming ASP.NET Web API, I was really looking more into converting my site, www.atmybase.com , into an SPA-like site. Thinking about it more... perhaps that's not appropriate, as it's a content site.

Comment: I have seen your site. You can't convert everything, but maybe some customs search performed by an user by inserting some words...can be implemented with SPA because a similar content is not accessible by search engines...this is the logic that might drive you...pages that in any case will NOT be reached by search engines, such as private users pages...and so on